# Time complexity of two approaches for replacing spaces in a string with '%20' Python

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

I have the following two algorithms to calculate this. Is there a difference in complexity between them? If so, what is the complexity of each? Are they both `O(n)`? The complexity of `append` is `O(1)`. Is `join` on a list `O(n)` also?

If someone can explain how to calculate the complexity of the second one would be great.

```
def replace_spaces(s):
    arr = []
    for c in s:
        if c == ' ':
            c = '%20'
        arr.append(c)

    return ''.join(arr)
```

```
def replace_spaces(s):
    return ''.join(['%20' if c == ' ' else c for c in s])
```

Comment: Use the stdlib functions: [urllib.parse.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote).

Comment: How does this answer my question about what is the time complexity of the 2 algorithms?

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer. Why do you care about the time complexity?

Comment: Because I need to be able to analyze this complexity.

Comment: But what *practical problem* you are trying to solve? If you want to know about time complexity *in general*, there's [a python-wiki article](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), and [many other guides](https://blog.teclado.com/time-complexity-big-o-notation-python/) available [elsewhere](https://stackabuse.com/big-o-notation-and-algorithm-analysis-with-python-examples/). However, it's unclear what relevance any of that has to replacing spaces in strings. SO is all about finding solutions to practical programming problems - it's not a tutorial site.